# How to Annotate/Label an Object (Arrow) in VPython?

Tags: python, vpython

I am using VPython to draw coordinate systems.

Since I did not find any readily avalible coordinate system object, I thus draw three mutual-perpendicular arrows to represent the coordinate system as follows:

```
y = arrow(pos=(0,0,0), axis=(6,6,0), shaftwidth=0.00001, color=color.red)
x = arrow(pos=(0,0,0), axis=(-6,6,0), shaftwidth=0.00001, color=color.green)
z = arrow(pos=(0,0,0), axis=(0,0,-10), shaftwidth=0.00001, color=color.blue)
```

Problem is that I cannot label/annotate them. I can only distinguish them by color, which is not very convenient.

**How can I write a `'x'` by the side of the `x object`?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `text` object to do that.

```
text(text='x', axis=x.axis, pos=x.axis)
text(text='y', axis=y.axis, pos=y.axis)
text(text='z', axis=z.axis, pos=z.axis)
```

For more information see the [vpython reference for `text`](http://www.vpython.org/contents/docs/text.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `label` object is more appropriate to label the axes, since it always faces forward, even if you rotate the scene. Look at the [VPython documentation](http://www.vpython.org/contents/docs/label.html) for details.

Example (untested):

```
label(pos=x.axis, text='x')
label(pos=y.axis, text='y')
label(pos=z.axis, text='z')
```